# Reading 2d Json object android

Tags: android, json

Hello i have this json:

```
{"m1":                 
    {"phone":"510000",
    "lon":-75.5898195,
    "postal":"050022",
    "address":"cll 19",
    "company":"my company",
    "saved":true,
    "address2":"adress my company",
    "lat":6.2418782},
"m0":
    {"phone":"85555555",
    "lon":-75.5898195,'
    "postal":"45895",
    "address":"cll 65 d 54",
    "company":"c1",
    "saved":false,
    "address2":"jhvbf",
    "lat":6.2418782}
}
```

Now, when i click on a marker on google maps, that info should appear on a drawer layout passing the marker to retrieve the marker id on that function:

```
private void openDrawerLayout(final Marker marker){
    try {
        JSONObject inf = markerId.getJSONObject(marker.getId());
        //JSONObject inf = (JSONObject) markerId.get(marker.getId());
        if(inf.getBoolean("saved")){
            String companyJs = inf.getString("company");
            String address1Js = inf.getString("address");
            String address2Js = inf.getString("address2");
            String postalJs = inf.getString("postal");
            String phoneJs = inf.getString("phone");
            company.setText(companyJs);
            address1.setText(address1Js);
            address2.setText(address2Js);
            postal_code.setText(postalJs);
            phone.setText(phoneJs);
        }else{
            address1.setText("");
            address2.setText("");
            postal_code.setText("");
            phone.setText("");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When i use this function markerId.getJSONObject(marker.getId()), is allways retrieving the first json object (m1), need help on how to retrieve the right id marker json

Answer (score 0):

If you're always getting m1, then marker.getId() is always returning m1. Make sure you're passing the correct marker in, and that your getId function is correct.

Also notice that since on m0 saved is false, you would not actually set any text on the view (you'd get all blanks).